# Catching 500-Internal Server Errors generically and returning a json

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I am coding some Spring REST services using Spring MVC. I have a requirement that any 500 (Internal Server Error) be sent back packaged as a json with Http Status = 500 and Http Body with the json string ["Internal Server Error"].
To do this i am extending OncePerRequestFilter and checking the status of Http Response. I am then constructing the body with the required json response.
Though this serves the purpose, it is messy. Is there a better design principle or spring/json class that I can configure with Spring which achieves the same purpose?

-Gotz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use the following structure:

1) Map HTTP 500 error to some view:

```
 <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errorView.htm</location>
    </error-page>
```

2) in your Controller create View which will return any Json Information you need.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/errorView.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleGet(HttpServletRequest req) {
     res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
     res.setContentType("application/json");
     res.getWriter().print("{\Error"\:\"Internal Server Error\"}");
}
```

Hope it helps.